# How to access an object while looping python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

Hey I am scraping an HTML site and getting issues when wanting to access some objects.

```
products = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser").findAll("div", {"data-rubrik":"Cars"})
```

^This results in an array of 100+ objects. Each of these objects contains an aria-label looking like that:

```
<div class="art artikelid an" data-alter="7" data-hauptrubrik="Cars" data-k="1666377008.07714">
<a aria-label="Ford Mustang"></a>
</div>
```

I want to loop through all of the objects and print the car name (aria-label) for each object.

This would be the right way to archive it in JS:

```
for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    let cars = products[i].split('aria-label="')[1].split('"')[0]; 
}
```

But i cant get it to work in python this is my attempt:

```
for cars in products:
                print(cars.split('aria-label="')[1].split('"')[0])
```

I hope someone can help me out.
Have a great evening :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
for cars in products:
    a = cars.find("a")
    if a:
        print(a.get("aria-label"))
```

Comment: thank you this worked but how if an object has multiuple "a" tags how would i get the 3rd or 4th one ?

Comment: @mxxim Then try `a = cars.find_all("a")[3]` or other index.